# Not able to draw on canvas html after deploying my model on heroku

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, heroku

I have trained a simple handwriting digit recognizer model using Keras, where we will predict outputs based on drawing and deploy it on the Heroku server using Flask. It worked correctly on the local server, but when I deployed it on Heroku, I could not draw anything. Can anyone please find what I am doing wrong here?

this is the frontend file (main.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<form action="/draw" method="GET">
    <fieldset>
        
    <input name="Tweet" type ='text' style='display:none' id='a'/>
    </fieldset>
 

<body onload="InitThis();">
<h1>Single digit recognizer using keras</h1>
<p> If you are getting wrong result then switch to large scale</p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JsCode.js"></script>
    <script>
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

function InitThis() {
    ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

    $('#myCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
        mousePressed = true;
        Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
    });

    $('#myCanvas').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        }
    });

    $('#myCanvas').mouseup(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
        $('#myCanvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
}
var a1=0;
function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = $('#selColor').val();
        ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        a1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL('image/png');
        document.querySelector('#a').value=a1;
    }
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}
    
function clearArea() {
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

</script>
    <div align="center">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
        <br /><br />
        
        <button onclick="javascript:clearArea();return false;">Clear Area</button>
        Line width : <select id="selWidth">
            <option value="11" selected="selected">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
        </select>
        Color : <select id="selColor">
            <option value="black">black</option>
            <option value="blue" selected="selected">blue</option>
            <option value="red">red</option>
            <option value="green">green</option>
            <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
            <option value="gray">gray</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
<div style="text-align:center">  
    <input type="submit" style="width: 300px; margin: 20 auto;" />
</div>  
</form>
<br>
<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %}
    <p style="font-size:50px">{{ result }}</p>
    
    {% endif %}
</div>
</html>
```

this is the backend file (app.py)

```py
import flask
from utils import *
import tensorflow as tf
# Use pickle to load in the pre-trained model
# Initialise the Flask app
app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

# Set up the main route

l=['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine']
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return(flask.render_template('main.html'))


@app.route('/draw')
def draw1():
    try: 
        a1 = flask.request.args.get('Tweet')
        model=tf.keras.models.load_model('Model1.h5')
        
        img=toImage(str(a1))
        
        prediction=model.predict_classes(img)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                         result=l[prediction]
                                         )
    except Exception:
        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                         result='Something went wrong please try again :)'
                                         )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

utils.py to convert base64 data to image

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
import io
import numpy as np
def toImage(s):
    imgstring = s[22:]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    im = im.resize((28,28))
    im = im.convert('L')
    im = np.array(im)/255
    im=im.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    return im
```

here is keras model ''' https://github.com/sachin327/draw/blob/main/Model1.h5 '''

all required files are uploaded here ''' https://github.com/sachin327/draw '''

Comment: Did you deploy/upload your JsCode.js as well?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes, basically all of my code(frontend) was written on a single file main.html(including javascript code), and I deployed that file on Heroku using flask. I don't have an extra javascript file.

Comment: Did you try to use developer tools of your browser to see which requests a fired and which error messages are produced? 

The JsCode.js question was because you still have its ````<script type="text/javascript" src="JsCode.js"></script>```` in your main.html. If there is no such file, however you incorporated the code in HTML itself, then this of course should not cause problems.